# USB device not recognizing in ubuntu 14.04 on lenovo Z510

Tags: usb, lenovo

I bought new Laptop Lenov Z510 i5, before yesturday it was detecting USB device. I even tried External Hard Disk and Reliance Data card but both are not recognising either.

Please help me in resolving this.

Thank You.

Comment: can you type lsusb in terminal & add its output to your question

Comment: Actually it is detecting now...the error seems to be sporadicoutput of lsusb

Comment: Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 19d2:ffe9 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 5986:029d Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: I faced same issue Again output of LSUSB                                     Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub                                                                Atheros communication device is missing also.....

Comment: dmesg output      



[   54.848593] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   54.869738] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (1208) terminated with status 1
[   54.869766] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   59.846388] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131115/nsarguments-95)
[   59.846677] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131115/nsarguments-95)

Comment: No actually none of USB is detecting....so there is no ttyUSB in /dev folder

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on  `/dev/ttyUSB0`. I just installed 14.04 on a new m78 and had to change the permissions so I could get to it.
This is the change I made

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Hope it helps